# Entity Framewok Failed adding migration with binary array

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've been working with EF 6.0 CodeFirst on a project and successfully added some migrations, but now I have a new migration which I can't apply. Here's the scaffold migration:

```
public partial class FileContentByteArray : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.JobsRecordHistories", "FileContent", c => c.Binary());
        AddColumn("dbo.JobsRecords", "FileContent", c => c.Binary());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.JobsRecords", "FileContent");
        DropColumn("dbo.JobsRecordHistories", "FileContent");
    }
}
```

And it fails with a very unclear message after running: update-database -verbose:

```
PM> Update-Database -verbose
Using StartUp project 'JobsManager'.
Using NuGet project 'TasksJobsLib'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the       target database.
Target database is: 'SchedulerJobs' (DataSource: 172.20.101.236, Provider:     MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201512141437137_FileContentByteArray].
Applying explicit migration: 201512141437137_FileContentByteArray.
alter table `JobsRecordHistories` add column `FileContent` longblob 
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved     for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner      runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String      targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Type is not resolved for member     'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.
```

I've successfully added a migration yesterday... I also tried setting the new property as nullable with null as default value but it didn't work.
I have ~300K records at JobsRecords and ~600K at JobsRecordHistories, so I thought maybe it has something to do with lots of updates it needs to do, and thus getting a timeout?

UPDATE: Now I see that the new column was indeed added to my tables! which is the worst thing, since now the code and the db are not up to date!!

Can anyone shed some light about the reason the update failed, the reason it succeeded altering the tables and what is the right move now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it:
a. I changed the timeout of the migration actions at the configuration section:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TasksJobsLib.TasksJobsDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        **CommandTimeout = 200;**
    }

    protected override void Seed(TasksJobsLib.TasksJobsDbContext context)
    {
        //nothing
    }
}
```

b. This change didn't work when I tried setting the newly added byte[] as nullable with null as default value. I don't know why.

c. I still don't like the output message of the update-database command. It shows no helpful details at all!